# View dependency injection with dagger 2

Tags: java, android, view, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I have a custom view extending a `TextView`. Where should I call my component to inject the view?

```
component.inject(customTextView);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, I've find out that I need to add the injection in the constructor of my custom view (in all of them, or make one call the other)

Example:

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {
   @Inject
   AnyProvider anyProvider;

   public CustomTextView(Context context) { this(context, null); }
   public CustomTextView(Context AttributeSet attrs) { 
      super(context, attrs);
      Application.getComponent(context).inject(this);
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you using dagger 2.11?
Can you show me who to get this: Application.getComponent(context)? Can't make my Application return anything but AndroidInjector. Thanks.

Comment: Your `ApplicationComponent` - returned by `applicationInjector()` - should extend `AndroidInjector<MyApplication>` so can be cast to `ApplicationComponent`. I got a compiler warning telling me to override the return type of `ApplicationComponent.Builder.build()` to clarify this. It's probably not good to call `applicationInjector()` multiple times as it will create the component many times so I'm storing a reference to it... not sure if that is best practice though. Maybe follow up in a new question.

Comment: @GuilhE ... use it, this returns dagger Component
daggerAppComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder().application(this).build();

Answer (score 3):

My general solution for that kind of thing is this

```
public class WelcomeView
        extends LinearLayout {
    private static final String TAG = "WelcomeView";

    public WelcomeView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public WelcomeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public WelcomeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }

    @TargetApi(21)
    public WelcomeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        if(!isInEditMode()) {
            Application.getComponent(context).inject(this);
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can use this() to make one constructor call another one, so you don't need to add init in all your constructors

Comment: True, but I like to make sure it's called from all my constructors, just in case Android does something weird :)

Comment: Isn't getting rid of the static methods one of the main points of dependency injection? But you are still calling a static method here. In activity and fragment I know how to avoid it but what about views?

Comment: You can also do `((CustomApplication)(context.getApplicationContext()).getComponent().inject(this);` if you want

Comment: @kingston I guess the question truly is where you obtain your `Component` from. I've seen solutions like singleton enum, global LinkedHashMap, MortarScope, custom ContextWrapper, etc.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce right that was my real question. Thank you for the clues

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE: Since 2.10 version of Dagger this answer is invalid.**

Custom view:

```
public class CustomView extends View {
    @Inject
    AnyObject anyObject;

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity) getContext();
        mainActivity.getComponent().inject(CustomView.this);
    }
}
```

Activity:

```
ActivityComponent mComponent;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mComponent = DaggerActivityComponent.builder()
                    .appComponent(getApp().getAppComponent())
                    .activityModule(new ActivityModule(MainActivity.this))
                    .build();
    mComponent.inject(MainActivity.this);
    ...
}

public ActivityComponent getComponent() {
    return mComponent;
}
```

Dagger2 component with Activity scope:

```
@ActivityScope
@Component(dependencies = AppComponent.class, modules = {ActivityModule.class})
public interface ActivityComponent extends AppComponent {

    void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);
    void inject(CustomView customView);
}
```

Scope:

```
@Scope
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ActivityScope {}
```

Comment: .activityModule(new ActivityModule(MainActivity.this))
this is depricated now.

Comment: @TusharPandey Yes, its been deprecated since 2.10 version of Dagger2. I need to update my answer soon.

Comment: `onFinishInflate(...)` won't be invoked if the custom view is instantiated programmatically.