# CustomView dependency injection with dagger 2 (within activity scope)

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36186085/view-dependency-injection-with-dagger-2).

So for instance, I have a `LiveData` implementation:

```
public class CustomLiveData extends LiveData<SomeEvent> {

    @Inject
    public CustomLiveData(@ActivityContext Context context) {
        //....
    }

}
```

that I want to inject into a custom view:

```
public class CustomView extends View {
   @Inject
   SomeApplicationProvider anyProvider;

   @Inject
   CustomLiveData dataProvider; 
   // Getting @com.di.qualifiers.ActivityContext  android.content.Context cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method. 
   // @com.di.qualifiers.ActivityContext android.content.Context is injected at com.repositories.CustomLiveData.<init>(context)
   // com.repositories.CustomLiveData is injected at com.ui.CustomView.dataProvider com.ui.CustomView is injected at 
   // com.di.ApplicationComponent.inject(view)

   public CustomView(Context context) { this(context, null); }
   public CustomView(Context AttributeSet attrs) { 
      super(context, attrs);

      // Works ok for application provider
      Application.getComponent(context).inject(this);
   }
}
```

And here is the rest of DI classes:

```
@ApplicationScope
@Component(
        modules = {AndroidInjectionModule.class,
                ActivityBuilder.class
        })

public interface ApplicationComponent extends AndroidInjector<MyApp> {

    void inject(MyApp application);

    void inject(CustomView view);

    @Component.Builder
    abstract class Builder extends AndroidInjector.Builder<MyApp> {

        public abstract ApplicationComponent build();
    }
}

@ActivityScope
@Module (subcomponents = MainActivitySubcomponent.class)
public abstract class ActivityBuilder {

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ActivityKey(MainActivity.class)
    abstract AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends Activity>
    bindActivityInjectorFactory(MainActivitySubcomponent.Builder builder);

    //...

}


@Subcomponent(modules = {MainActivityModule.class})
public interface MainActivitySubcomponent extends AndroidInjector<MainActivity> {

    @Subcomponent.Builder
    abstract class Builder extends AndroidInjector.Builder<MainActivity> {

    }
}

@ActivityScope
@Module
public class MainActivityModule {

    @Provides
    @ActivityContext
    public Context provideActivityContext(MainActivity activity) {
        return activity;
    }

    // Seems to be wrong or not enough!?
    @Provides
    public CustomLiveData provideCustomLiveData(@ActivityContext Context context) {
        return new CustomLiveData(context);
    }
}


@Qualifier
public @interface ActivityContext{
}
```

Note, that I don't get any compiler complaints if `CustomLiveData` is injected into `MainActivity` instead into the view.
Thanks!

Comment: Did you get any compile error when injecting `CustomLiveData` into `Custom` view? Please post it along with your question.

Comment: the message was included in the CustomView part. See "// Getting @com.di.qualifiers.ActivityContext  android.content.Context cannot ....."

Comment: Can u post the `@ActivityContext` ?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

## tl;dr Don't inject model layer dependencies inside custom `View` objects

Subclasses of `View` are not good targets for Dagger 2 injection. `View` objects are meant to be drawn and not must else, hence the name "view". The constructors for [`View`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) should make this clear; they are designed for inflating `View` objects from attributes specified in XML. In other words, a `View` object should be able to be specified in a `layout.xml` file, inflated at the appropriate point in the lifecycle, and then obtained using `findViewById(int id)`, [Butterknife](https://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) or data binding. In this way, the best custom `View` objects take no dependencies.

If you want to link a `View` and some data from the model layer, the standard pattern is to write an Adapter like those for `RecyclerView` and `ListView`. If this is not possible, using a setter (e.g., `setData()`) is preferable to passing dependencies from the model layer in the constructor or requesting injection from within one of the lifecycle methods of the `View`.

If instead you inject your `LiveData` object inside an Activity or Fragment using the `AndroidInjector` class the correct `Context` will be provided without you having to do anything. This explains your comment "I don't get any compiler complaints if CustomLiveData is injected into MainActivity instead into the view."

Once you have injected the `LiveData` object into the Activity, use one of the above methods (an adapter or a setter) to associate the data with your custom `View`. See the Google Android Architecture example [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/todo-mvp-dagger/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/tasks/TasksFragment.java) where elements from the model layer are injected using Dagger 2 and then associated with a `ListView` using `findViewById` and `setAdapter()`

Link to the Dagger 2 issue where injection of `View` objects is discussed:

https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/720

Comment: I'm building AR views which require a class that requires class that deals with sensor values, calculations and filtering also class to get location. Shouldn't i inject this classes to my class that extends View or SurfaceView, etc. ?

Comment: @Thracian I still reckon you should try and write an adapter if it's possible

Comment: I don't display sensor value or location value as list. Sensor and location outputs are required to convert positions of point of interests on map to screen. Views inflated use constructor with Context and Attribute. I wonder if i should do method injection to inject sensor and location manager classes.

Comment: I also need location and sensor values in Activity other than ARView.

Comment: If view is not good target for dagger then dagger is not good tool for injection. Because target should be independent, and there is no special restrictions to inject anything into anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Your Dagger hierarchy looks like this: 
`appcomponent` -> `activitycomponent`

You try to inject activity `context` inside view, that depends on `appcomponent` directly.

It's not possible since there is no method that could provide activity context in `appcomponent`. Instead, inside view, you should retrieve activity  (for example using `getContext`), extract `activitycomponent` from it and only then inject `CustomLiveData`.