# Dagger2 injection of a ViewModel without @Inject constructor

Tags: android, dependency-injection, viewmodel, dagger-2, android-viewmodel

I have large Android ViewModel classes that tend to have a lot of dependencies (most of them are DAOs from Room, one per SQLite table). Some have more than 10 dependencies.

This is fine but the `@Inject` constructor is bloated with arguments, and contains only boilerplate code to set the injected members from the constructor arguments.

I wanted to switch to "regular" injected members, identified individually with an `@Inject` annotation, like other (dumb) classes.

This fails for Android related classes (although ViewModels are advertised as non-Android dependent, e.g. they don't use the Android framework) such as activities and fragments.

The workaround for that is to use a factory, which is injected from the `Application` class using the nice `HasActivityInjector`, `HasServiceInjector`, etc. interfaces.

Dagger doesn't provide any `HasViewModelInjector`, so if I persist in injecting members individually instead of injecting the constructor, here's what I'm given:

> error: [dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)] XXXViewModel cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides-annotated method. This type supports members injection but cannot be implicitly provided.

**If I create a module that has a `@Provides` annotation to create the ViewModel, this doesn't inject individual members.**

Did I miss something (my last sentence is what's most important in my question) or is it simply not possible to inject members, and I *have* to inject the constructor?

---

A bit of code.

What I want:

```
class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {
    @Inject
    MyDao myDao;
}
```

versus what I need to do:

```
class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private final MyDao myDao;

    @Inject
    MyViewModel(MyDao myDao) {
        this.myDao = myDao;
    }
}
```

First block of code (what I want) requires this method in a module:

```
@Provides
MyViewModel provideMyViewModel() {
    return new MyViewModel();
}
```

**but in this case the `myDao` field is null**. How to inject the `@Inject`-annotated members?

I want to avoid the use of the 2nd block of code, which tends to create a huge constructor bloated with many arguments, should I need to inject a lot of members.

Comment: I have read this [nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46304549/334493) that explains that we should _Always prefer constructor injection or provide it from a module where you can do additional setup steps_; however this doesn't cover the member injection.

Comment: You can use my method,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53956997/7558125

Comment: @PratikMhatre: thanks, but I switched to Koin, which has a much simpler API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways of injection and I think you are referring to field injection. Field injection, unlike constructor injection, must be triggered manually. To do that, define a method in your component with the view model as parameter.

```
void inject(ViewModel viewModel)
```

And then call this method from your view model constructor perhaps.

```
class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private final MyDao myDao;

    @Inject
    MyDao myDao;

    public MyViewModel() {
        MyComponent mycomponent = DaggerMyComponent.....
        myComponent.inject(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, I knew that I needed to inject manually, I just couldn't figure it out.

Comment: What I actually did is that I edited the `InjectableViewModelFactory` (that is found everywhere online) to be injected with the application instance (so that I can access the application component), and then call `application.getComponent().inject((MyViewModel) creator.get())`. Your answer greatly helped me, thanks!