# Dagger 2.11 Injecting in OkHttp Authenticator

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

I have been using the dagger 2.11 AndroidInjection with no problems until i tried to Inject my Retrofit service in an OkHttp Authenticator in order to handle session timeouts.

AndroidInjection allows only for injections in Activities,Fragments,Services,ContentProviders and BroadcastReceicers.

My questions is how can i use the new Dagger AndroidInjection in a class that is not in the above list?

Comment: If i'm not wrong, you can just use @Inject why do you need to use AndroidInjection?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45075204/how-do-i-use-androidinjection-class-in-custom-views-or-other-android-classes/45195327#45195327).

Answer (score 0):

Just use inject to provide Retrofit, in the same module you provide also okhttp that is used by retrofit

```
@Singleton
@Provides
OkHttpClient providesOkHttpClient(){
    return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(RETROFIT_API_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(RETROFIT_API_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(RETROFIT_API_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();
}

@Singleton
@Provides
Retrofit providesRetrofit(OkHttpClient client){
    return new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .client(client)
                    .build();
}
```

Then in your class:

```
public class MyClass {
   Retrofit mRetrofit;

   @Inject 
   public MyClass(Retrofit retrofit){
      mRetrofit = retrofit;
   }
}
```

Comment: This wont work in my case because the Authenticator is created when the okHttpClient is instantiated, so the the injection of the retrofit instance needs to be Lazy.
Even If i inject the retrofit instance in my authenticator even with "Lazy" its always null.

Comment: I have the same issue. How to get Retrofit in Authenticator